# Запятая при уточнениях

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли в данном случае запятая после процентов?

Это на 1,5 млн тонн, или на 3%(,) меньше, чем годом ранее.

Answer (score 1):

Если ставите первую запятую, то нужна и вторая, чтобы закрыть оборот.

Если хотите выделить, то лучше использовать скобки. Они часто используются для вспомогательных значений (чисел). Но можно и не выделять ничего, это подходит для разговорного стиля (например: *могу купить за доллар или за 71 рубль*). Выделить нужно, если это отчёт (деловой стиль): там есть основной вариант, а вспомогательный идёт не наравне, а в скобках. Союз "или" в скобках можно опустить. Если эти проценты очень важны, то тогда необходимо использовать запятые.

Предлагаю такой вариант (но необходимо знать о важности процентов):
*Это на 1,5 млн тонн (на 3%) меньше, чем годом ранее.*